# SQL | How to display "NA" if row doesn't exists, without switch case

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-function

I have two tables,

Table 1:

| studentId | department |
| --- | --- |
| S01 | Mech |
| S02 | Mech |
| S03 | CSE |

Table 2:

| studentId | Result |
| --- | --- |
| S01 | Pass |
| S03 | Fail |

I want to display : studentId, Result of Mech department, for those students whose result is not given in table 2, result should show "Absent".

Desired output,

| studentId | Result |
| --- | --- |
| S01 | Pass |
| S02 | Absent |

How can I do it without using switch cases? (Using only: Joins, Sub queries, Function, Group by, Having, Where, etc.) (i.e Basics only)

Using, SQL (Oracle)

I tried too much, but was unable to display "Absent" for "S02"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a left join between the two tables, along with `COALESCE` to render `Absent` as the result for any mechanical student missing in the second table.

```sql
SELECT t1.studentId, COALESCE(t2.Result, 'Absent') AS Result
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t2.studentId = t1.studentId
WHERE t1.department = 'Mech';
```

Comment: Thank you !  Also, can we do it using "inner joins" only?

Comment: You need a left join here to prevent non matching students from being filtered off.  You could also use a subquery approach.